# Deprecation warnings

Tags: gradle

I have this code:

```groovy
task fatJar(type: Jar) << {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'mvc.MvcMain'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    with jar
}
```

I got this warning:

> Configuring child specs of a copy task at execution time of the task has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
>   Consider configuring the spec during configuration time, or using a
>   separate task to do the configuration.
>               at build_b2xrs1xny0xxt8527sk0dvm2y$_run_closure4.doCall

and this warning:

> The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action)
>   instead.

How to rewrite my task?

Comment: There's a short write-up of why at http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2016/11/gradle-goodness-replacing-operator-for.html

Answer (score 1):

The line that is essentially causing both of the warnings is

```groovy
task fatJar(type: Jar) << {
```

In the Gradle version you are using (which is presumably some `3.x` version, the `leftShift` Groovy operator is calling the `doLast` method. Everything passed to `<<` (`leftShift`) is executed in the `doLast` task action of that task.

To fix `leftShift` deprecation

> The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.

You would want to change your task to:

```groovy
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
  doLast {
    manifest {
      attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
                 'Implementation-Version': version,
                 'Main-Class': 'mvc.MvcMain'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    with jar
  }
}
```

Now, however, you will still see the other warning:

> Configuring child specs of a copy task at execution time of the task has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Consider configuring the spec during configuration time, or using a separate task to do the configuration.

This warning is telling you that you are modifying the configuration of your `fatJar` task at execution time, which is a bad thing to do. It messes upGradle up-to-date checking and incremental builds.

The way to fix this warning, is to follow one of the suggestions from the previous CLI output. For example, here is *"configuring the spec during configuration time"*.

```groovy
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
               'Implementation-Version': version,
               'Main-Class': 'mvc.MvcMain'
  }
  baseName = project.name + '-all'
  with jar
}
```

Notice there is no longer a `doLast` block since we aren't adding any different actions.

Answer (score 0):

it might look about like this; this should at least fix one of the warnings:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
                   'Implementation-Version': version,
                   'Main-Class': 'mvc.MvcMain'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        } 
    }
    with jar
}
```