# The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0

Tags: android, gradle, ionic3

The `Task.leftShift(Closure)` method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use `Task.doLast(Action)` instead

I am getting this error when trying to build android or run. Using cordova-android 6.4.0
ionic-cli - 4.3.1
node - 8.11.1
cordova - 8.0.0
gradle - 4.6

I have tried downgrading cordova-android to 6.3.0 , 6.2.3
Upgrading cordova-android to 7.0.0, 7.1.1
But other things fails on changing cordova-android version
Removed everything and started from cloning and installing node modules

Comment: I'd say this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41619040/deprecation-warnings/55821992#55821992 but the author never selected an answer there.

Comment: You can find the exact cause of this warning by running Gradle with the `--warning-mode all --stacktrace` command line arguments.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone getting this while build fail. This is a warning and not the cause of build failure. In my case it wasn't giving any error So I assumed that this is the error.