# unable to generating an Android App Bundle from your Ionic app (without Android Studio)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, build.gradle, gradlew

This is mostly Duplicate of [build fail for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56153674/the-task-leftshiftclosure-method-has-been-deprecated-and-is-scheduled-to-be-re) but no answer is yet available and my scenario is little different so putting it again.

In my my case I am able to build apk properly and I want to create a app bundle after successful of command

`ionic cordova build android --prod --release` by running this cmd I am able to generate the apk.

After that I am going to `/platform/android` and running `./gradlew bundle` and here I am getting this error

```
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'bundle' is ambiguous in root project 'android'. Candidates are: 'bundleAppClassesDebug', 'bundleAppClassesDebugAndroidTest', 'bundleAppClassesDebugUnitTest', 'bundleAppClassesRelease', 'bundleAppClassesReleaseUnitTest', 'bundleDebug', 'bundleRelease'
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those that end up here and find that the `--packageType=bundle` flag doesn't seem to work, pay close attention to the note [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/android/#using-flags):

> Note: You should use double -- to indicate that these are platform-specific arguments, for example:
>
> `cordova run android --release -- --keystore=../my-release-key.keystore --storePassword=password --alias=alias_name --password=password --packageType=bundle`.

Notice the empty `--` after `--release`. The below assumes you already have your keystore and password configuration in `build.json`:

```
cordova build android --packageType=bundle // flag is silently ignored, generates apk
cordova build android -- --packageType=bundle // flag works, generates aab
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you! Very easy to overlook

Comment: Thanks you for this!

Answer (score 5):

Ionic has built-in command line to generate the .aab format.

AAB:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- -- --packageType=bundle
```

It will generate automatically the .aab at android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release

APK:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

May it helps someone.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In other answers it seems that you can run:

```
./gradlew bundleRelease
```

In my case it's not working.
I solved upgrading android platform version for ionic.

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@8
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

After that, if you go in platforms\android folder you are able to do

```
./gradlew bundle
```

I didn't check gradle versions for both android versions but I suppose it's changed.

Regards,Vincenzo

Comment: After performing these procedures worked for me, when inserting the command cordova build android --prod --release -- --packageType=bundle was generated the .aab file instead of the .apk :)

Answer (score 3):

My requirements were different to the original question but this still might be useful for some.
After upgrading Cordova the build command below was producing an `.aab` file where  prior to update it was producing an `.apk`. Our build pipeline was set up for signing an APK file so I wanted to make APK the default.

```
$ ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

When I upgraded from cordova 8.x.x to 10.x.x This command defaulted to an .aap file being produced

adding the `-- --packageType=apk` did not work.

I had to create a build.json in the root cordova app directory with the following:

```
{
    "android": {
        "debug": {
            "packageType": "apk"
        },
        "release": {
            "packageType": "apk"
        }
    }
}
```

This worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to build successfully by updating build.json and running the command `cordova run android --release`!

What I did is:

1. Upgrade Gradle form v6.7.1 to v7.3.3 (Windows version, download .zip and setup "Path").
2. build.json add `,"packageType": "apk"`.

Build app-release.apk successful:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, keys are already generated.

```
cordova build android --prod --release -- --packageType=bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- -- --packageType=bundle

This is the right answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).