# Package type "bundle" is not supported during cordova run

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova

I am not able to generate bundle for android. APK is generated correctly but while exporring bundle for play store, I am getting the following errors.

```
Package type "bundle" is not supported during cordova run.

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:412:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:552:15)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:449:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:552:15)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:313:12)
    at Pipe.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  code: 1,
  killed: false,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'cordova run android --release --buildConfig'
```

Also I would need some help removing these warnings:

```
> Configure project :app
WARNING:: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
```

```
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
```

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
```

```
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"extension-level"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
Warning: Errors limit exceeded. To receive all errors set com.sun.xml.bind logger to FINEST level.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
```

I am just trying to export the bundle which was working fine the last time I used the project.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61364268/unable-to-generating-an-android-app-bundle-from-your-ionic-app-without-android) help?